# How to organize SSH users and setup them?

Tags: ssh, users, ssh-tunneling, sshd, sftp

I want all users to use your public/private key to any kind access to my server. Into SSH configurations, I will setup 3 groups:

1. `sshaccess`: Users can use shell, SFTP and tunnels;
2. `sftpaccess`: Users can't use the shell, but can use SFTP;
3. `mysqlaccess`: Users can't use the shell, but can use TCP Forwading to port 3306.

I will allow only theses 3 groups to use SSH connection:

```
AllowGroups sshaccess sftpaccess mysqlaccess
```

To users with `sftpaccess` group, I will force SFTP and lock user in your home folder:

```
Match Group sftpaccess
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory %h
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

To users with `mysqlaccess` group, I will allow tunnel on port 3306:

```
Match Group mysqlaccess
    Banner no
    PermitTunnel yes
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
        PermitOpen 127.0.0.1:3306
```

But, let's suppouse I have the user `caique` and he needs:

- Acessing the SFTP, locked in your home folder;
- Acessing the MySQL Tunnel to connect with your credentials.

I don't want to create an user to SFTP an another user to MySQL Tunnel, so what is the best way to achieve this?

I don't want expose the MySQL port, therefore I use MySQL Tunnel. But, in my tests, I could not use Tunnel for users associated with `sftpaccess`, what am I missing?

Comment: You have set `PermitTunnel no` for `sftpaccess`, therefore this group can't create tunnels.

Comment: @Panki when I apply both groups `sftpaccess` and `mysqlaccess` to an user, the instructions are not replaced by the last group matched?

Comment: @caiquearaujo No, the _first_ match is used for any setting. Maybe it is just going to work if you define `Match Group mysqlaccess` before `Match Group sftpaccess` in your `sshd_config` (but I haven't look really carefully at it, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

How about a section like:

```
Match Group sftpaccess Group mysqlaccess
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory %h
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    Banner no
    PermitTunnel yes
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
        PermitOpen 127.0.0.1:3306
```

Admittedly, this requires duplication, and may or may not work depending on if sshd loads all of a users groups (I suspect it does).

Alternatively, you could make a user-specific `Match` (which tends to assume you won't get more such users.

I suspect the ordering of the rules matters, but I'm not sure if this should be first or last (relative to the other two).  I think it should be first.